# Diagonal of an open/closed immersion is an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

> A morphism $(f,f^\sharp):(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ is an *open immersion* (resp. *closed immersion*) if $f$ is a topological open immersion (resp. closed immersion) and if $f^\sharp_x$ is an isomorphism (resp. if $f^\sharp_x$ is surjective) for every $x\in X$.

> Let $f: X \to S$ be a morphism of schemes. Consider the fiber product $X \times_S X$ of $X$ viewed as an $S$-scheme with itself. The identity map $1_X : X \to X$ satisfies $1_X \circ f = f$, so that there is a unique morphism $\Delta_{X/S}: X \to X \times_S X$ by the universal property of the fiber product. This morphism is called the *diagonal* of $X$ with respect to $S$.

If $X \to S$ is an open immersion or a closed immersion, is the diagonal $\Delta_{X/S} : X \to X \times_S X$ an isomorphism?

I think I am able to prove injectivity. Indeed, by the universal property of fiber products, if $p_1, p_2: X \times_S X \to X$ are the two projections, then $p_1 \circ \Delta_{X/S} = p_2 \circ \Delta_{X/S} = 1_X$. I think this proves injectivity, since $\Delta_{X/S}$ has a left inverse.

Comment: Yes. In other words, open immmersions and closed immersions are monomorphisms in the sense of category theory.

Comment: @ZhenLin how can I prove it?

Comment: You haven't used the hypothesis that you have an immersion!

Comment: @ZhenLin I know, it is just that I am stuck and I do not know how to use it. Can you please help here?

Comment: Could you do it if the exercise were about embeddings of topological spaces?

Comment: @ZhenLin I mean, when we have sets, for a map $f: X \to S$, I think $X \times_S X = \{ (x,y) \in X^2 | f(x) = f(y) \} = \{(x,x) | x \in X\}$ by injectivity (the projection on $X$ is an inverse). So surjectivity is guaranteed. Moreover the map is injective and continuous. Moreover the map is closed/open, so the map is an homeomorphism. But in this case the diagonal map is defined by a universal property and not simply by $x \mapsto (x,x)$. So please at least give a hint on how to use the open/closed condition. It's that one thing I have right under my nose but I have not time to figure it out.

Comment: The open/closed condition is not relevant, in fact. For locally ringed spaces the argument is basically the same: you have to show that if you have if $f$ is an immersion then $f \circ x_1 = f \circ x_2$ implies $x_1 = x_2$ for any morphisms to $X$.

Comment: @ZhenLin okay maybe I got this: $f \circ p$ is an immersion, and $f \circ p \circ \Delta_{X/S} \circ p = f \circ p$, so if I prove what you said, $\Delta_{X/S} \circ p = 1_{X/S}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin I think what you requested can be proved by using that $stalk_y$ is a contravariant functor and that $f_y$ is always right-cancellable, (it is either surjective or an isomorphism) so that $f \circ x_1 = f \circ x_2 \implies x_{1,y} \circ f_y = x_{2,y} \circ f_y \implies x_{1,y} = x_{2,y}$ for every $y$, so $x_1 = x_2$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You should also say something at the level of points but I think you've figured it out.

Comment: @ZhenLin what do you mean by "you should say something at the level of points"?

Comment: A morphism of locally ringed spaces is a continuous map of topological spaces as well as a homomorphism of sheaves of rings. Right???

Comment: @ZhenLin yes, indeed this procedure yields an inverse in the category of schemes, so the corresponding map between topological space has a continuous inverse and the natural transformation between the corresponding sheaf of rings is "invertible", because it is an isomorphism at the level of staks